# Lambda inside function definition Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

```
(define (fn lst)
  (filter (lambda (item) (not (symbol=? item 'sym))) lst))
```

We pass in `lst`, but inside `(lambda (item) (not (symbol=? item 'sym)))` our variable  `lst` is never used.  Evaluation?

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. That invalidates the answers that people have taken time to write. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet you posted combines two concepts which can be explained in isolation (and might make more sense that way): *lambda expressions* and *higher-order functions*.

### Lambda expressions

In Scheme/Racket, functions are ordinary values, just like numbers or lists. To create a number, you just type it, like `3` or `25`. To create a list, you use the `list` function, like `(list 2 4 6)`. To create a function, you use the `lambda` form.

Normally, when you define a function, you use `define`. For example, here is a function that adds 1 to a number:

```
(define (add1 x)
  (+ x 1))
```

But this is really just a shorthand syntax. The full way of writing the above definition out would look like this:

```
(define add1
  (lambda (x)
    (+ x 1)))
```

As you can see, it uses `lambda`.

Why would using `lambda` directly ever be useful, though, if the `define` shorthand is shorter and easier to read? Well, to understand that, you must consider higher-order functions.

### Higher-order functions

Most functions take simple values and produce simple values. For example, the `add1` function above takes a number as an argument and produces a number as a result. However, remember above that I mentioned that functions are values, too. For that reason, functions can actually accept other functions as arguments, and they can even produce other functions as results. These functions are called “higher-order functions”.

The `filter` function is a higher-order function. It takes a function and a list, and it uses the function to select which elements should be kept in the result. For example, it can be used to select all the even numbers in a list:

```
> (filter even? (list 1 2 3 4 5))
'(2 4)
```

Note that `even?` is a function, and it’s being passed as an argument to `filter`. This is totally okay, and it’s actually extremely useful! There are many functions in Scheme/Racket that are higher-order, and these sorts of functions are an important part of programming in a “functional” style. For example, the `map` function lets you provide a function to apply to each element of a list:

```
> (map add1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
'(2 3 4 5 6)
```

---

This is all well and good, of course, but what if you wanted to add a number other than 1 to each element of a list? Well, you could always define a new function that added the right amount:

```
> (define (add25 x)
    (+ x 25))
> (map add25 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
'(26 27 28 29 30)
```

However, this would be extremely silly. It would be like if you had to give names using `define` to all of your numbers, too, instead of just typing them into the program directly. For small, simple functions that will only be used once, giving them a name is unnecessary. For that, you can use the `lambda` form directly:

```
> (map (lambda (x) (+ x 25))
       (list 1 2 3 4 5))
'(26 27 28 29 30)
```

This is what is happening in the snippet in your question. You *could* give the inner lambda a name, like this:

```
(define (not-an-apple? item)
  (not (symbol=? item 'apple)))

(define (eat-apples lst)
  (filter not-an-apple? lst))
```

However, in this case it’s easier to just write the function inline, since having a separate `not-an-apple?` function is probably not terribly useful.

Comment: @AnamayaGarodia The `filter` function just applies the provided function to each element in the list; `item` just happens to be the name given to the first argument for that function.

Comment: @AnamayaGarodia Effectively, yes, but not just for the first element. Internally, `filter` is recursive.